# Python, Iteration over a list of 500 json elements takes long time, any possible streamline?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

the following snippet of code iterates over 500 elements of such
[valueA, valueB, valueC]
and takes roughly 24 seconds to execute a very simple logic

```
for myItem in myDict:
    try:
        itemDate= datetime.fromtimestamp(int(myItem[0]))
        if (dateStart < itemDate):
            listOfData.append(myItem)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Any advice to iterate faster?

Thanks

Comment: I've also tried to import the list into a pandas dataframe and then iterate over it, it takes a long time anyway.

Comment: I do not believe you. Iterating over a dict with 500 elements is practically instantaneous. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: you are right, check my answer. The problem was in the mongodb cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of head scratching and debug and finally pointed the problem.
It's not the iteration by itself, but looping over a mongodb cursor.

The code was 
    records = collection.find(myquery)
    for record in records:
   .... looping over items of a record.

Replacing

records = collection.find(myquery)

with 
record = collection.find_one(myquery)

boosted the iteration speed.